# Exception when using Entrust middleware in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, entrust

I have installed the [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#installation) package in my Laravel 5.1 application by adding it to my composer.json file and running composer update and followed all of the instructions to the letter. I am trying to use their middleware to protect some routes but I get the following exception:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class App\Http\Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission does not exist
```

Here is the contents of my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "LaravelCollective/html": "5.1",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~5.0",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "~3.0",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.1",
        "thujohn/twitter": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.5",
        "cviebrock/image-validator": "2.0.*@beta"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Http/Helpers"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant content of my config/app.php file:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    'yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider', // data grid
    'DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider',
    'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider',
    'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
    'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider',
    'Cviebrock\ImageValidator\ImageValidatorServiceProvider'
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    'Breadcrumbs'   => 'DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Facade',
    'Datatables' => yajra\Datatables\Datatables::class,
    Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'Image_helper' => 'App\Http\Helpers\Image_helper',
    'Twitter' => 'Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter',
]
```

Here is the content of my App\Http\Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'clientIpCheck' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ClientIpCheck',
        'role' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
    ];
}
```

And here is how I am trying to use the middleware in my routes.php file:

```
// secure admin routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'permission:access_admin_area'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@index']);
});
```

I'm pretty sure I've followed their instructions to the letter, it was all working until I tried to use their route middleware. Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/402

Comment: Add trailing slash in the start of middleware `Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class` and remove `Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,` from `facade` array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the code in the installation instructions is wrong. The route middleware definitions need a backslash on the front.

Broken example:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'clientIpCheck' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ClientIpCheck',
    'role' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
];
```

Fixed example:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'clientIpCheck' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ClientIpCheck',
    'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
];
```

Thanks to [xaoc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169572/xaoc) for the heads up!

Comment: i was looking at your code and figured you missed the \ glad you caught it

Answer (score 0):

Check This [Failed to Attach ENTRUST Middleware](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/402)

Or try to create your `MiddleWares` Manully

1- Go to `Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware` in `vendor` directory

2- Copy all `MiddleWares` from `Middleware` directory

3- Paste all in `App\Http\Middleware` and change the path in `$routeMiddleware[]` to your app middleware dir

Note: don`t forget to change namespace after copy